# Create array of objects from graphql response

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, ecmascript-6

I have a response from graphql that I want to reformat and assign to a variable so that I can keep using them across my app.

GraphQL response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "organization": {
            "tables": {
                "edges": [
                    {
                        "node": {
                            "id": "1wer45",
                            "name": "Node One",
                            "internal_id": "12345"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "node": {
                            "id": "j8IrxJ425",
                            "name": "Node Two",
                            "internal_id": "54321"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to assign the following format to an array:

```
[
    "Node One": { id: '1wer45', internal_id: '12345' }
    "Node Two": { id: 'j8IrxJ425', internal_id: '54321' }
]
```

I want the above to be assigned to an array that I can keep reusing.

My code:

```
const reFormat = func((result) => {
  let test = {};
  let obj1 = {};
  let table_details = result.data.data.organization.tables.edges.map((d) => {
    obj1["id"] = d.node.id;
    obj1["internal_id"] = d.node.internal_id;
    test[d.node.name] = obj1;
    return test;
  });
  console.log(table_details);
});
reFormat({ query: tables("13456") }).then((res) => res);
```

THis is not giving me an error but is not giving me what I want either. I want to assign my reformatted array to a variable.

Comment: That is not a valid syntax for either an object or an array.

Comment: What is `pipefyFunction`? Why dou you only `console.log` the result, did you mean to `return` it? What's the point of `.then((res) => res)`?

Comment: You need to move the `obj1 = {}` object creation inside the loop. Also you don't want/need to use `map` to create a new array, you rather seem to be interested in `test` as the result. Try to get rid of `table_details`, use a normal `for` loop, and log `test` afterwards.

Comment: Btw, instead of `tables { edges { node { … } } }` in your graphql query just use `tables { nodes { … } }`

Comment: @Bergi when I just return it, it returns nothing